# How to seamlessly Integrate a Document Collection with a Custom Post Type in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, document-library, jet-engine

I am in the midst of developing a WordPress website and have encountered a hurdle while attempting to integrate a document collection within a Custom Post Type, created via JetEngine. My objective is to streamline the process of adding documents from the Media Library to this post type, and subsequently, display a list of these documents on the website complete with thumbnails (as shown in the media library).

Moreover, I wish to customize the displayed name of each document and ensure that upon clicking, the documents open in a new tab for the users. Is there a plugin or a method that could facilitate this functionality?

I stumbled upon a plugin named "Custom Post Type Attachment PRO" which partially met my needs, but fell short as it didn’t allow for customizing the displayed name of the uploaded documents, nor showcasing the thumbnails from the media library. However, I appreciated the ease with which I could add new documents from my custom post inside WordPress using this plugin.

Here is how it should somehow look like, though maybe with bigger thumbnails:
[Image of how the plugin result looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChCuB.png)

Comment: have you considered making the post type first in the mu-plugins folder so that it keeps all your data and then using ACF to create 2 custom fields that you can hook into at your index.php file?

Comment: No, but the best solution for now that my Client liked was just using the Block-Editor to insert the links directly, which solved the issue.